# How to remove an array within the protected array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

My data returns look like:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [admin] => Admin
            [user] => User
            [abcd] => Abcd
        )

)
```

I want to remove `admin` array in above result. I tried this way `unset($data->items->admin)` Getting the error message `Property [items] does not exist on this collection instance.`.

Comment: if `items` is array and `admin` is associative key so You can do: `unset($data->items['admin'])`

Answer (score 1):

Protected is a visibility permission set. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

from the looks of the error it looks like your forgetting to extend the sub class.

Here is an example of what your trying to do.

```
class a{
    protected $b;
    function __construct(){
        $this->b = Array('test'=>Array());
    }
}

class b extends a{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();// construct extended class
        out($this->b); //returns Array ( [test] => Array ( ) ) 
        unset($this->b['test']);
        out($this->b); // returns Array ( )
    }
}

function out($arr){ // function to output text
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
    echo "</pre>";
}

$b_test = new b();
```